# How do I simulate a button click, not just firing the event but also the clicking animation?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to design an UI that includes a some buttons and also some keyboard shortcuts for users that don't want to use the mouse. In order to provide some extra visual feedback, is there a way to have my keyboard events visually simulate a click on the buttons, making them play the same animation they would have played if they had been clicked with the mouse?

For example, I'd like to be able to make it so that when the user starts pressing "Q" the corresponding button enters the "clicked" state and it goes back to the usual look as soon as "Q" gets released. Additionally, having the button's onclick fire at the end would be nice but that is not a hard requirement for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replicate the `:active` pseudo-class with your own custom class. (`.active`)

**HTML**:

```
<button id="demo" onclick="demoHandler()">Test</button>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
function simulateClick(el) {
    var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    el.dispatchEvent(evt);
}

var hotkeyActive = false;
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if(!hotkeyActive && e.keyCode === 81) {
        hotkeyActive = true;
        demo.className = 'active';
        var keyupHandler = function (event) {
            hotkeyActive = false;
            demo.className = '';
            simulateClick(demo);
            window.removeEventListener('keyup', keyupHandler, false);
        };
        window.addEventListener('keyup', keyupHandler, false);
    }
}, false);

var demo = document.getElementById('demo');
function demoHandler() {
    alert('Button Clicked!');
}
```

**CSS**:

```
button {
    padding: 5px;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border: 1px solid rgb(122, 122, 122);
    border-radius: 2px;
    outline: none;
}

button.active, button:active {
    border: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0 rgb(0,0,0);
}
```

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/r6R86/4

Comment: I was working out something similar but you wrote it out more completely and faster, so I removed mine. Good job. I would suggest that since this is such a small bit of code that you include the example in your actual solution so that when others search for it, it is easier to see the answer.  They can always go to the fiddle to test it out.

Comment: When I click the button with the mouse it doesn't look exactly like it looks when press the key on the keyboard. Is there a way to make them look the same in a cross browser way? Or should I go ahead and also reimplement ":active" from scratch so they at least match?

Comment: @hugomg -- you will find it much easier to re-implement :active with your own styling. You can attempt to mimic the browser's, but it's constantly changing, and they are all different.

Comment: initMouseEvent is deprecated according to WebStorm.